# how to modyfiy an object values or keys using Template literals on server side? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to back-end , I have a deeply nested object on server side just testing for now no DB yet, it's an object i want to modify dynamical.
I send a certain data from my front-end a do some styling on them then I want to put them in the Obj
I feel like my implementation is wrong any idea how to populated this object using those incoming data ?
I simply want the final item in the spitted array to update the value of B
Also A,B,C,D coming from the front-end have the same names of the value of the object at hand.

Thanks.

```js
// Deeply nested Obj
const obj = {
    A: {
        B: {
            C: 'D',
        }
    }
    }
    // Router 
router.post('/datasender', (req, res, next) => {
    let data = JSON.stringify(req.body)
    let slice = data.slice(10, -2);
    let split= slice.split(".")
    // split looks like ['A','B','C','D']
    // filter diffrent condtions since split[0] will change 
    if (split[0] === 'A') {
       obj[`${split[0]}`].[`${split[1]}`].[`${split[2]}`] = split[3]
    }
    /* Not used yet New condition 
        if (split[0] === 'A') {
       obj[`${split[0]}`].[`${split[1]}`].[`${split[2]}`] = split[3]
    }*/
```

Comment: so you want the frontend to modify the object in the backend?

Comment: hi, well the front end will send data some data are constants other will change, to the back-end then they will get stored at back end and send back to front-end. so yes i want the front-end to mod the back-end according to the incoming input yet we are talking just data storage here. no other major mods.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webject allows you to "share objects online"

Comment: I want to learn how to do it to be honest rather than using a dependency.

Comment: aw but i made it ;-; nevertheless i'll explain how that big repository works.. actually, there's a really simple way to JUST do what u wanna

Comment: so, where are you trying to add values to the object?

Comment: ah, I see your pattern.. the variable `split` has the path to take and the last index being the value to place right?, so obj.a.b.c='d'

Comment: Exactly, its a confusing example sorry for that

Comment: I answered btw, please check when ready :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the variable `split` has the indexes before the last one as the `path` and the last one as the `value`

With that, one more function and an if statement SHOULD grant your wishes

The function reads a path and an object and returns the nested object, the if statement is for "if valid path, then write frontend request"

```
// Deeply nested Obj
const obj = {
    A: {
        B: {
            C: 'D',
        }
    }
}

//takes map/path and returns the object
function mapToFile(m,files){
    var x=files
    if(!m||!m.length){return(files)}
    var errort=0
    m.forEach(a=>{
      if(x[a]){x=x[a]}
      else{errort=1}
    })
    if(errort){return(0)}
    return(x)
}

// Router 
router.post('/datasender', (req, res, next) => {
    let data = JSON.stringify(req.body)
    let slice = data.slice(10, -2);
    let split= slice.split(".");
    var index=split.length-2;
    var myObj=mapToFile(split.slice(0,index),obj);
    if(myObj){ //if not, path is invalid
      myObj[split[index]]=split[index+1]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :), will this mutate the default object as well ?

Comment: yes, because objects are pointers, `myObj` is a nested object inside `obj`, you can `console.log(obj)` after to see the results for yourself @Jackhammer . Also if the answer is correct could you please mark?

Comment: thanks a lot for the effort. have a good one.

Comment: yea, and check out my package if u have time :D